# Three.js revision 69 vs 75 - issue with Points/PointsMaterial and texture handling

Tags: javascript, three.js, textures, transparency

I have been learning Three.js using Three.js Cookbook recently.
All examples there are build on revision 69.

Example [06.02 Create Particle System from Scratch](https://github.com/josdirksen/threejs-cookbook/blob/master/06-particles-postprocessing/06.02-create-particle-system-from-scratch.html) uses `PointClound` and `PointCloudMaterial` to render textured grid of vertices. It renders fine with no texture artifacts with revision 69.

However when I replace Three with newest revision 75 and replace:

- PointCloud to Points
- PointCloudMaterial to PointsMaterial
- use TextureLoader.load() instead of ImageUtils.loadTexture()

as suggested by warnings. I get issue with artifact on every texture.
I have changed texture to size of powers of 2, but I does not help.

Opaque texture issue:
[image: opaque texture issue]

The same faulty render from different angle - looks good:
[image: from different angle - looks good]

Is it a bug or I miss something?

Comment: Try `pointsMaterial.alphaTest = 0.5`.

Comment: @WestLangley thanks for hint, but this only solves part of texture that is 100% transparent,  but the semi-transparent parts (near the center of texture in this case) are still fully opaque.

Comment: You can try changing the 0.5 value, but likely you need to modify your texture so the semi-transparent parts are more transparent. Also try `pointsMaterial.depthTest = false` or `pointsMaterial.depthWrite = false`.